# Focus on a application

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Can I create any shortcut to focus on an application?

For instance <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and Safari is active and on top of other windows, <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> Pages and so on.

I remember a long, long time ago, that was possible with <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with many apps available. I personally prefer [Better Touch Tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net), because You can do much more than just assign keyboard shortcuts. There's window snapping and most of all - custom mouse/trackpad gestures. Here's example:

[image: Better Touch tool with keyboard shortcut assigned to focus on Safari]

With this I can press <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to focus on **Safari.app**.